# ios Firebase Dynamic Link not opening installed app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, dynamic, hyperlink

I've looked at other previous questions about this topic, and I haven't found the solution for my problem.
I've followed this [Getting started with Firebase Dynamic Links on iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLBjAg6HvG0&t=33s), however if I click on the universal link for testing, `https://appName.page.link`, I get the following message:

```
Invalid Dynamic Link
    Requested URL (https://appName.page.link/) must be a parsable and complete DynamicLink.
    If you are the developer of this app, ensure that your Dynamic Links domain is correctly configured and that the path component of this URL is valid
```

The previous message makes me think that the created page created by Firebase is created yet, however when I visit the page: 
`https://appName.page.link/apple-app-site-association`, I get the following data:

```
{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID":"TeamID.com.example.appName","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]}]}}
```

This means that the page has been successfully created.
I have verified that the TeamID has been set properly set in the Firebase settings, and also that the TeamID is the same from XCode and from the Apple developer account.
The URLSchemes, set in Xcode is `com.example.appName` and inside the Signing & Capabilities in the Associated Domains has the domain: `applinks:appName.page.link`

Is there anything that I'm missing to configure?

Comment: Facing same issue and its yet not fixed. If you got solution then pls let me know.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this issue as well following the video. If you continue in the video he mentions that there is a bug for iOS where you might need to completely uninstall the app, restart your device, and then reinstall the app.

for reference:
https://youtu.be/KLBjAg6HvG0?t=532

Comment: I believe that was pretty self explanatory. There is no work that I wish to upload. Just uninstall your app you are developing. Retart your device by turning it off and then back on. And then reinstall your app that you are developing and that is a potential fix for this issue. I referenced a link in the main response that will take you to a youtube video explaining the answer further if desired.

Comment: The youtube link is to Firebase's official channel.  Unfortunately this is the only place they acknowledge the issue.  This should be the accepted answer.  You can track the official bug here: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4999496467480576

Comment: Just commenting because the answers here didn't seem to come to an agreement, but this worked perfectly for me. Thanks very much! The comment about the link not working because it didn't have any trailing path is wrong. I believe the URL showing an error page is simply because iOS didn't handle the dynamic link properly (otherwise safari would have known to close itself), and it's not a Firebase issue, which I originally thought.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is still the solution on iOS 15

Answer (score 0):

Did you created dynamic link here? Firebase > Dynamic Links > New Dynamic Link. Your link should looks like https://AppName.page.link/shareLink

Comment: I also did that, but according to the video made by Firebase, the link you open the app :(

Comment: Hmm propably you missed something. You can do it again, or create link programitacally. I did it 2 days ago and it works well for me. Here you have tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create?authuser=1 I have hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

I think this behavior is expected, clicking on the URL prefix (https://appName.page.link) without any path will not take the user to the app since the configurations (deep linking, campaign tracking, platform behavior, etc) is not set up yet.

But once you create a new link along with the prefix (e.g. https://appName.page.link/createdLink), it should work properly.

Comment: however, in the video explanation that I linked in the question, he says that it should open the application

Comment: Yes. That is what the video said. I am struggling on this one too. I expected that the app will open but does not.

Answer (score 0):

The bit that tripped me up was that I added "Associated Domains" to the "Release" tab instead of the "All" tab.  So when I was running on my app, I'd also get the Invalid Dynamic Link error.

[image]